# Mailkit POP3 message spool doesn't contain all emails

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

I'm using mailkit to get emails from Gmail using the POP3 protocol. I have set gmail to download all messages (Even ones already downloaded) and I use the something like the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MailKit.Net.Pop3;
using MailKit.Security;

namespace PopTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new Pop3Client()) {

                await client.ConnectAsync("pop.gmail.com", 995, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("your_email_address", "your_password");

                Console.WriteLine(client.Count);

                await client.DeleteAllMessagesAsync();
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

whilst this works fine. I have <strike>500</strike> 358 messages in my inbox but the message spool (client.Count) is only giving me a count of 269. After I have downloaded the 269 messages, if I attempt to run this same code again it will give me the other <strike>231</strike> 89 messages. Why doesn't the message spool show all <strike>500</strike> 358 messages to begin with? Why is it seemingly limited to 269 messages? Is this expected behavior?

--UPDATE--

Protocol log below:

First Time:

```
Connected to pops://pop.gmail.com:995/
S: +OK Gpop ready for requests from 90.254.77.87 f62mb14296326lfe
C: CAPA
S: +OK Capability list follows
S: USER
S: RESP-CODES
S: EXPIRE 0
S: LOGIN-DELAY 300
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: X-GOOGLE-RICO
S: SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
S: .
C: AUTH PLAIN
S: + 
C: ***************
S: +OK Welcome.
C: CAPA
S: +OK Capability list follows
S: USER
S: RESP-CODES
S: PIPELINING
S: EXPIRE 0
S: LOGIN-DELAY 300
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: X-GOOGLE-RICO
S: .
C: STAT
S: +OK 269 13212695
C: DELE 1
C: DELE 2
C: DELE 3
C: DELE 4
...
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
...
C: QUIT
S: +OK Farewell.
```

Second Time:

```
S: +OK Gpop ready for requests from 90.254.77.87 d22mb31260803lfj
C: CAPA
S: +OK Capability list follows
S: USER
S: RESP-CODES
S: EXPIRE 0
S: LOGIN-DELAY 300
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: X-GOOGLE-RICO
S: SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
S: .
C: AUTH PLAIN
S: + 
C: *************
S: +OK Welcome.
C: CAPA
S: +OK Capability list follows
S: USER
S: RESP-CODES
S: PIPELINING
S: EXPIRE 0
S: LOGIN-DELAY 300
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: X-GOOGLE-RICO
S: .
C: STAT
S: +OK 89 8499575
C: DELE 1
C: DELE 2
C: DELE 3
C: DELE 4
...
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
S: +OK marked for deletion
...
C: QUIT
S: +OK Farewell.
```

I also stumbled across this post from 2011:

> You can normally only download messages once through Gmail's POP service. If you use "recent mode" (put "recent:" in front of your username when signing in), you can access all recent messages through POP.
>
> BTW, Gmail's POP service ignores labels and message status, so it does not matter if they are in the Inbox or if they are unread. **In normal mode, it provides access to about 300 of the oldest messages that have not been downloaded. In recent mode, it provides access to all the messages added to the account in the last 30 days.**

Link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/9qlVgLCXIzQ

I suspect then that this a gmail issue and nothing to do with Mailkit. I guess as a workaround I can just reconnect the client after quitting and check if there is any more mail to download.

-- UPDATE --

After further research I have also found this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089246?hl=en

which explains more about both modes and the **"about 250"** message limit.

Comment: Are you sure the 231 messages didn't arrive after your initial request?

Comment: 100% sure. I can replicate this again and again just by removing the 'await client.DeleteMessageAsync(i);' and resetting the gmail settings. It's rather odd O.o

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] - we need to see how `client` is created, for example.

Comment: Updated with an example console app. I can reproduce the error with this.

Comment: Try getting a [Protocol Log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) which will show you exactly what commands MailKit sends and exactly what the server returns.

Comment: Updated the question with protocol logs! : )

Comment: Are you using recent mode?

Comment: I don't think so as the behavior seems consistent with 'normal mode', Though at the moment, I don't know what mode it is running in or how to change it. : / . Updated the question with more info on the two modes.